# Rails and outside libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use this [gem](http://bn4r.rubyforge.org/) in my rails application, but when I add it to my gem file and try to use it I get an error saying that it did not found the methods required (I am using it inside a controller). Also require 'bn4r' does not help as rails tells me that it cannot load such a file, which is odd. I can access the library from the development console with no problems any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: How looks your line in the `Gemfile`? Did you run `bundle install` after adding the line? How looks your code in which you try to use that gem?

Comment: well I think the gem has been installed correctly as I can invoke it from the console but not inside a controller. The error that gets thrown is uninitialized constant RequestController::BayesNet, which is odd as BayesNet is not part of the RequestController. If I change that to module name which is Bn4r like so B4nr::BayesNet.new I get uninitialized constant RequestController::Bn4r instead as the error.

Comment: Did you restart your server after changing the `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the gem to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'bn4r'
```

install it:

```
$ bundle install
```

Restart the server and use it like this:

```
BayesNet.new
```

Comment: actually, restarting my machine fixed it, not the server :P. Now it works without the global module reference.